# php mysql select by month between records

Tags: php, mysql

I've this MySQL table my_table:

```
+-------+------------+-----------+
|Student|    Date    | Classroom |
+-------+------------+-----------+
|     1 | 2018-01-01 |       101 |
|     2 | 2018-01-01 |       102 |
|     3 | 2018-01-01 |       103 |
|     1 | 2018-03-01 |       104 |
|     2 | 2018-06-01 |       103 |
|     3 | 2018-09-01 |       104 |
|     1 | 2018-11-01 |       106 |
|     2 | 2018-12-01 |       101 |
+-------+------------+-----------+
```

The students stay in the assigned classroom till changed.

I'm trying to get which classroom they were in for a certain month.

For example in October(10), student 1 was in 104, 2 was in 103, and 3 was in 104.

I'm really unsure on how to proceed with this one so any help is appreciated.

Currently using this query based on Strawberry answer

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM my_table x 
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table y 
ON y.student = x.student
AND y.date < x.date
WHERE x.date <= LAST_DAY('2018-10-01')
GROUP BY student
```

Comment: What is your question, and what would the desired result look like. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "For example in October(10), student 1 was in 104, 2 was in 103, and 3 was in 104.'" if you try to explain your expected results make sure your example data contains this data..

Comment: @RaymondNijland The sample does not contain the data point. That IS the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(Student INT NOT NULL, Date DATE NOT NULL, Classroom INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(student,classroom));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2018-01-01',101),
(2,'2018-01-01',102),
(3,'2018-01-01',103),
(1,'2018-03-01',104),
(2,'2018-06-01',103),
(3,'2018-09-01',104),
(1,'2018-11-01',106),
(2,'2018-12-01',101);

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT student
            , MAX(date) date 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE date <= LAST_DAY('2018-10-01') 
        GROUP 
           BY student
     ) y 
    ON y.student = x.student 
   AND y.date = x.date;

+---------+------------+-----------+
| Student | Date       | Classroom |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | 2018-03-01 |       104 |
|       2 | 2018-06-01 |       103 |
|       3 | 2018-09-01 |       104 |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thx It's working as intended. I will test it further, but I think I can change it accordingly from now on

Answer (score 0):

Here's a go at it (snippet to go in a stored procedure; assumes table called example & output to table months). It produces a row per student for each month of the range.

```
drop table months;
create table months (month date, student integer, classroom integer);
set @month = (select min(date) from example);
start_loop: LOOP
    insert into months select @month, s1.student, classroom from
    (select student, max(date) as maxdate from example where date <= @month group by student) s1
    join example s2 on s1.student = s2.student and maxdate = date;
    if @month = (select max(date) from example) then
        leave start_loop;
    end if;
    set @month = @month + interval 1 month;
END LOOP start_loop;
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's break the problem into two parts. Firstly, find all the rooms which have been allocated to student A so far and sort them using the date. Next, find the record which is just before or equal to the required month.

For example:

Consider student 1. We get

```
+-------+------------+-----------+
|Student|    Date    | Classroom |
+-------+------------+-----------+
|     1 | 2018-01-01 |       101 |
|     1 | 2018-03-01 |       104 |
|     1 | 2018-11-01 |       106 |
+-------+------------+-----------+
```

Now, let's say for month June we try to find month just less than or equal to 2018-06-01 to get the required room number. I hope this will help.

Comment: this answer will generate even more questions and doesn't even try to answer the question..

Comment: But, the selected answer does the same thing as I said.